# Test to identify correlation between the age, weight,cholestral, BP on diabetes

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What type of test should be applied to identify correlation between

- the age
- weight
- cholestral
- BP on diebtes?

I need to identify pattern between these variables.

Comment: A regression (probably a simple linear regression) might give you better insights than an hypothesis test.

Answer (score -1):

Simple correlation matrix would do. This gives the relationship between every possible combination of the 2 variables at a time.

Comment: The question distinguishes "diabetes" as a response, indicating that a multiple regression analysis is desired and needed, not a correlation-based one, despite the colloquial use of "correlation" in framing the question.  This is such a prevalent confusion in some fields (which start and end their analyses with tests of correlation coefficients) that I feel obliged to indicate the distinction with a downvote.